# Is there a multimedia library for Python that is an alternative, portable, object-oriented compared to Pygame, Pyglet and derivatives?

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet, cocos2d-python

For 2D game development in Python there is a library or binding that has a serious and sustainable development, is pythonic and has a simple and complete design of classes for application development.

I've learned Pygame, Pyglet, PySFML and cocos2d. But I think that, in some cases, can be very specific limiting the degree of abstraction that gives us a high level language like Python.

For example by the two ways of load an image on Pyglet:

```
pyglet.resource.image()
```

or

```
pyglet.image.load()
```

Comment: You're looking for something "serious", "sustainable", "pythonic", "simple", "complete", and meanwhile not "very specific" or "limiting the degree of abstraction". What you are asking is pretty subjective. What might seem "simple" and "pythonic" to one person might seem "limiting" or "overly specific" to another.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big list maintained at [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries), probably you should check [Python-Ogre](http://python-ogre.org/).

Comment: Is Python-Ogre really suitable for 2D game development?  It seems to advertise itself as 3D.

Comment: You are right, Python-Ogre is mainly for 3D games, but python wiki link worth a look.